# IEEE 754 and range of values between languages

Tags: java, c#, c, ieee-754

The specification of C, Java and C# says that floating point values
are formatted according to IEEE 754.

However the range of values it seems to be different:

- for **java**, `float` 1.4E-45 to 3.4028235E38 ; `double` 4.9E-324 to
  1.7976931348623157E308
- for **C#**, `float` -3.402823E+38 to 3.402823E+38 ; `double` -1.79769313486232E+308 to 1.79769313486232E+308
- for **C**, `float` -3.4×10-38 to 3.4×1038 ; `double`  -1.7×10-308 to 1.7×10308

So what are the real IEEE 754 range of values?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather ask why the discrepancy and if those languages strictly follow the  IEEE 754 standard?

Comment: To me the ranges seem to be the same, just expressed with a different number of significant digits.

Comment: @Lindbäck, are those range of values conforming to range of values of IEEE 754 specification? I didn't find nothing about this.

Comment: The java range is for the smallest positive non-zero float to the largest float. The C# and C ranges are showing negative and positive versions of the largest magnitude float and double. The range is the same for all of them as long as all use IEEE754.

Comment: They do. See for example: http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/References.xhtml#tables

Answer (score 1):

> The specification of C, Java and C# says that floating point values are formatted according to IEEE 754.

Jave and C#, yes.  C, no.  C in fact expressly permits a variety of numeric formats, and although most implementations in fact do use IEEE-754 representation, C does not require it.

> So what are the real IEEE 754 range of values?

IEEE-754 defines several floating-point formats.  The ones relevant to your question are the single-precision and double-precision binary floating-point formats (binary32 and binary64).

The range of *positive*, *normalized*, values for binary32 is `1.1754945E-38` to `3.4028235E+38`.

The range of *positive*, *normalized*, values for binary64 is `2.2250738585072014E-308` to `1.7976931348623157E+308`.

IEEE-754 formats are sign/value formats, so for for every supported positive value, there is a corresponding negative value.  IEEE-754 can also express numbers of even smaller magnitude than the minimums given above, but *with reduced precision*.  These are called "subnormal" numbers.  The smallest positive subnormal number expressible in binary32 format has just one bit of precision, and decimal value approximately `1.4E-45`.  The binary64 format supports an even smaller minimum subnormal number, with decimal value approximately `4.9E-324`.

The discrepancies you think you see result from you comparing different quantities, and / or expressing them to different precision or in different representations.

The Java quantities you report are presumably taken from `Float.MIN_VALUE`, `Float.MAX_VALUE`, `Double.MIN_VALUE`, and `Double.MAX_VALUE`.  These are respectively the minimum positive subnormal and maximum values expressible in IEEE-754 binary32 and binary 64 formats.  Java also offers `Float.MIN_NORMAL` and `Double.MIN_NORMAL` which provide the smallest positive *normalized* values in their respective formats.  These all map exactly to the various limiting values of the IEEE-754 formats.

I'm not a C# guy, but the limiting values you specify there are the overall (signed) minimum and maximum values of the binary32 and binary64 formats.  The maximums are the same as Java's.  The minimums are not comparable to Java's, because they express a different thing, but do observe that they have the same magnitude as the maximums, with opposite sign.

I'm not sure where your limits for C come from, and it appears you mis-typed the maximums.  You have certainly expressed them to lower precision than they actually have.  The minimums you give correspond to the minimum negative values expressible in binary32 and binary64 formats, the same as C#, and equally incomparable to the minimum positive values given for Java.  The maximums look like the same maximums as both C# and Java, but expressed to lower precision and a bit mangled.